# interval by 4 using sql - Mysql

Tags: mysql

I've a table and i want that data is interval by 4 or, when i'm using modulo the record is not that i expected, PFB `

```
SELECT (DATE_FORMAT(subscribed_from, '%Y-%m')) AS date_ FROM subscription
WHERE operator = 'tim'
AND DATE_FORMAT(subscribed_from, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN  '2013-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
GROUP BY (DATE_FORMAT(subscribed_from, '%Y-%m'));
```

it will show record like this

```
2013-01 
2013-02 
2013-03 
2013-04 
2013-05 
2013-06 
2013-07 
2013-08 
2013-09
```

i want take only data interval by 4, this below is record that i expected.

```
2013-01
2013-05
2013-09
2014-02
```

and also for interval by 2, this below record is that i expected

```
2013-01 
2013-03 
2013-05 
2013-07 
2013-09
```

if i using `modulo % 2` it will start from 2013-01 and jump by 2, but the problem if the where range i want to start from 2013-02, 02 it self not showing on the result. so if the where clause the month start from 2 it will given the interval such as 2,4,6,8,10,12

Comment: http://www.webveteran.com/blog/web-coding/mysql/mysql-select-every-nth-record/

Comment: thanks, but actually that modulo is interval by first row that detected, but if i choose some data example start data is from 2, it is now showing the correct result. your sample only showing data start from 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT date_, SUM(the_metric_you_want_to_aggregate)
FROM (
  SELECT 4*FLOOR(
   (DATE_FORMAT(subscribed_from, '%Y%m') - 201301)
   /4) AS date_,
   the_metric_you_want_to_aggregate
  FROM subscription
  WHERE operator = 'tim'
  AND subscribed_from BETWEEN 20130101000000 AND 201412315959
) AS ilv
GROUP BY date_
```

(where 201301 is the year/month start of the range you are selecting by - assuming that is the reference for the 4-month aggregation)

Note that enclosing column references in functions (`...DATE_FORMAT(subscribed_from, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN...`) prevents the use of indexes.

Comment: Great answer with deep understanding!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use variables. Here is sample for interval by 4.

```
SET @row_number:=0;
SELECT date_ from (
SELECT (DATE_FORMAT(subscribed_from, '%Y-%m')) AS date_,@row_number:=@row_number+1 FROM subscription 
WHERE operator = 'tim' AND DATE_FORMAT(subscribed_from, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN  '2013-01-01' AND '2014-12-31' 
GROUP BY (DATE_FORMAT(subscribed_from, '%Y-%m'))
    ) as tbl where @row_number % 4=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

let says i'm using this method to generate the intevals, but i want the start number is from my input, let says it start from 4 and if the condition put %4 should be the output is 4, 8 ,12 ....

```
enter code here

SET @row:=0; 
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT
    @row := @row +1 AS rownum
FROM (
    SELECT @row) r, subscription
) ranked
WHERE rownum %4 = 1
```

Comment: for interval 2 you should replace "row_number % 4=0;" with "where row_number % 2=0;"  in my answer

Comment: hi pvb, thanks for your update. that scripts is working, but my question is, what about if the input start is from 4 and i use interval 4, output will show like this 4, 8, 12, .......

Comment: @Pvb please view my comment below